# Wigner $d$-matrix for $j=1$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum

In Sakurai's *Modern Quantum Mechanics* p.198-199, he states that for the matrix
$$J_y^{(j=1)} = \frac{J_+-J_-}{2i} = \frac{\hbar}{2} \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -\sqrt{2}i & 0 \\
\sqrt{2}i & 0 & -\sqrt{2}i \\
0 & \sqrt{2}i & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
we have the relationship:
$$\left(\frac{J_y^{(j=1)}}{\hbar}\right)^3=\frac{J_y^{(j=1)}}{\hbar}$$

However, when I use this in a problem it yields undesirable results. So I verify it in Mathematica. It turns out that
$$-2\left(\frac{J_y^{(j=1)}}{\hbar}\right)^3=\frac{J_y^{(j=1)}}{\hbar}$$
with a factor of -2.

As a result, I can't figure out the final result using Taylor expansion of $\exp(iJ_y\beta/\hbar)$:
$$\exp(iJ_y\beta/\hbar) \to 1-\left(\frac{J_y}{\hbar}\right)^2(1-\cos\beta)-i\left(\frac{J_y}{\hbar}\right)\sin\beta$$

[image: Wigner d-matrix for j=1]
[image: Mathematica]

Comment: 1. You haven't stated an explicit question. 2. I suspect your explicit question would be off-topic as homework-like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the wrong command. Use MatrixPower[J/h,3] to calculate cube of J/h.

In[7]:= MatrixPower[J/h, 3]

Out[7]= {{0, -(i/Sqrt[2]), 0}, {i/Sqrt[2], 0, -(i/Sqrt[2])}, {0, i/
  Sqrt[2], 0}}

Clearly, this is equal to J/h.