# Euler Rotattion for j$\geq$ 1

Tags: quantum-mechanics, rotation

I am trying to understand Euler Angles as given in Sakurai.  Specifically, with the case j=1, where it is stated ($\hbar=1$)

> For j=1 ONLY, we can replace exp(-i$J_y\beta$)$\rightarrow 1-J_y^2(1-\cos(\beta))-iJ_y\sin(\beta)$

And that results in the rotation matrix as shown in this SE question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/166307/wigner-d-matrix-for-j-1)

Now my question:  suppose I did not want to use the fact that $J_y^3=J_y$, so I would have to explicitly calulate $\exp(-iJ_y\beta$).  Keeping it somewhat simple  and sticking to j=1 where I have the result, I have
$$\exp(-iJ_y\beta)=\sum(-iJ_y\beta)^n/n!=1-iJ_y\beta-J_y^2\beta^2/2+i\beta^3J_y^3/6+...$$
Evaluating this seems tricky as $J_y|1,m\rangle$~$|1,-1\rangle-|1,-1\rangle$.  However, I know that we can have eigenstates of $J_y$ that go as $a|1,-1\rangle+b|1,0\rangle+c|1,1\rangle$

Can I use the knowledge of these eigenstates to simplify the calculation to get the same result as above?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the eigenstates of $J_y$ in a very simple way:

For $j=1$ as you have, let $|1, \mu\rangle$ be the eigenstates of $J_y$ ($\hbar = 1$),
$$
J_y|1, \mu\rangle = \mu |1, \mu\rangle\;\;, \mu = -1, 0 , 1\\
|1, \mu\rangle = a_\mu |1,-1\rangle + b_\mu |1,0\rangle + c_\mu |1, 1\rangle
$$
Then the states $|1, \mu\rangle$ are also eigenstates of $e^{-i\beta J_y}$, since 
$$
e^{-i\beta J_y} |1, \mu\rangle = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\left(-i\beta J_y\right)^n}{n!}|1, \mu\rangle} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\left(-i\beta \mu\right)^n}{n!}|1, \mu\rangle} = e^{-i\beta \mu}|1, \mu\rangle
$$
Now let
$$
|\psi\rangle = \alpha_{-1}|1, \mu=-1\rangle + \alpha_0 |1, \mu=0\rangle + \alpha_{+1}|1, \mu=+1\rangle
$$
be an arbitrary state in the $j=1$ subspace and look at $e^{-i\beta J_y} |\psi\rangle$, $J_y |\psi\rangle$, and $J_y^2 |\psi\rangle$:
$$
e^{-i\beta J_y} |\psi\rangle = \alpha_{-1}e^{-i\beta J_y}|1, \mu=-1\rangle + \alpha_0 e^{-i\beta J_y}|1, \mu=0\rangle + \alpha_{+1}e^{-i\beta J_y}|1, \mu=+1\rangle = \\
= \alpha_{-1}e^{i\beta}|1, \mu=-1\rangle + \alpha_0 |1, \mu=0\rangle + \alpha_{+1}e^{-i\beta}|1, \mu=+1\rangle
$$ 
or 
$$
e^{-i\beta J_y} |\psi\rangle = \cos\beta \left( \alpha_{-1}|1, \mu=-1\rangle + \alpha_{+1}|1, \mu=+1\rangle\right) + \\
+\; \alpha_0 |1, \mu=0\rangle + \\
+ i\sin\beta \left( \alpha_{-1}|1, \mu=-1\rangle - \alpha_{+1}|1, \mu=+1\rangle\right) 
$$
and
$$
J_y |\psi\rangle = - \alpha_{-1}|1, \mu=-1\rangle + \alpha_{+1}|1, \mu=+1\rangle
$$

$$
J_y^2 |\psi\rangle = \alpha_{-1}|1, \mu=-1\rangle + \alpha_{+1}|1, \mu=+1\rangle
$$
Substituting the last two expressions in the expression for $e^{-i\beta J_y} |\psi\rangle$ yields
$$
e^{-i\beta J_y} |\psi\rangle = \left(\cos\beta\right) J_y^2 |\psi\rangle + \alpha_0 |1, \mu=0\rangle - i\left(\sin\beta\right)J_y |\psi\rangle 
$$
and already accounts for two of the desired terms. All that is left to do is to express the term $\alpha_0 |1, \mu=0\rangle$ likewise. For this, note that we have
$$
\alpha_0 |1, \mu=0\rangle = |\psi\rangle - \left(\alpha_{-1}|1, \mu=-1\rangle + \alpha_{+1}|1, \mu=+1\rangle \right) = \left(I - J_y^2 \right)|\psi\rangle
$$
Tallying up we get that for any $|\psi\rangle$ in the $j=1$ subspace
$$
e^{-i\beta J_y} |\psi\rangle = \left[ I - J_y^2\left(1 - \cos\beta\right) - i\left(\sin\beta\right)J_y \right] |\psi\rangle 
$$
and so the restriction of $J_y$ to this subspace amounts exactly to 
$$
e^{-i\beta J_y} = I - J_y^2\left(1 - \cos\beta\right) - i\left(\sin\beta\right)J_y
$$